# How to determine the type of "Fragment" object that is passed

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-adapter

I have three classes that make use of my custom adapter, and therefore, I would need to pass them as `Fragments`.

My thing works, but I am having difficulty distinguishing between the fragments.

I currently have something like this as my constructor:

```
public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<UserInfo> arrayList, UsersOne fragment){
    this.arrayList = arrayList;
    this.fragment = fragment;
}
```

My question is, I have `UsersTwo`, and `UsersThree` that are both `fragments` and both need the `CustomAdapter`. How do I modify my constructor such that it caters for all three and I can call their method calls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `instanceOf`

Do this

```
if(fragment instanceOf UsersOne){
    // take action for UsersOne
}
else if(fragment instanceOf UsersTwo){
   // take action for UsersTwo  
}
else if(fragment instanceOf UsersThree){
    // take action for UsersThreee
}
```

Comment: This works, thanks mate. I have accepted your answer